Highlight org-pretty-entities in a custom color background
I'm using org-pretty-entities t to enable pretty entities like \gamma or \to.
But I want to be able to highlight them in a different background color which helps me differentiate that these are pretty entities. Is it possible to implement in a hook?
Please note that I'm pretty new to emacs and elisp

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info
